# Cannot install ruby because missing libssl1.0-dev and libssl-dev however cannot install them either

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-18.04, libssl

### TLDR

- I cannot install ruby because I am getting the Error: libssl-dev and libssl1.0-dev missing

---

- Full error below:

```
rvm install ruby-2.6.3 
Installing required packages: libssl-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl-dev',
please read /home/swordfish/.rvm/log/1625810467_ruby-2.6.3/package_install_libssl-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

---

- I cannot simply install libssl-dev or libssl1.0-dev as when I do the same error pops up! How do I fix this? I am very close to just updating to ubuntu 20
- ubunto 18.04
- rvm -v 1.29.12

---

### Full story

I was attempting to modify a heroku app to use jemalloc for memory allocation. Along the way while attempting to install this gem into ruby on rails I modified my computers ssl packages. libssl-dev. As the original error was I needed to install it. I installed it then had the exact error of not having it on my system. I removed it to reinstall it and I get no change. Currently when I use ruby version manager (rvm) to install ruby I get this error:

```
ruby-2.2.0 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.2.0..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/18.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system....
Installing required packages: libssl1.0-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl1.0-dev',
please read /home/swordfish/.rvm/log/1625807135_ruby-2.2.0/package_install_libssl1.0-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

- One of the attempts to fix can be found here:
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/446691/in-ubuntu-13-04-cannot-install-libssl-dev
- There are others I have attempted but they are just a variation of the above link

Comment: what happens when you run `apt install libssl1.0-dev` manually?

Comment: I get the exact same error! It's really frustrating.

Comment: which same message? I'm assuming you tried to run `apt` as root, via `sudo`?

Comment: full error:  Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/18.04/x86_64/ruby-2.5.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating systemswordfish password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': ..-
swordfish password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update':
..
Installing required packages: libssl-dev
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl-dev',
please read /.rvm/1_ruby/package_install_libssl-dev.log installation failed status:100

Comment: can you just run the `apt install libssl1.0-dev` rather than trying to let RVM do it?

Comment: No it has the same error. Currently I'm working on just getting SSL in my system to fix the issue.

Comment: I think I discovered the problem!
which openssl
>/home/user/miniconda3/bin/openssl
bin which is where openssl is put was moved by miniconda3. This has to be it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a true answer but a work around.

This was a complicated issue made even more complex with miniconda3. I installed that program for Machine Learning. This program inserted itself in the file path that rails was using for authentications. In the long run I just uninstalled miniconda3. Reinstalled WSL, and reinstalled Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04. Now I no longer have the issue with the deprecated libssl-dev as it's all brand new.